# Seems booting in rescue mode Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, reboot, boot-repair

From yesterday evening Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop is now booting in a "strange" mode, with icons, text and everything bigger and larger than normal (looks in rescue mode).

This is the complete output of `boot-repair` :

```
boot-repair-4ppa130                                                  
[20210605_1032]

============================== Boot Info Summary     
===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of 
/dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of  
/dev/sdb.

sda1:        

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
/etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: 
    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the 
Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi 
/efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi 
/efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
/efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected    
=================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS  
CurrentSession on sda1

============================ Architecture/Host Info     ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-55-generic    
root=UUID=f5046f8e-a21c-44f7-aa0c-86eb09cf922f ro 
quiet splash vt.handoff=7


===================================== UEFI  
=====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode 
for this installed-session.
SecureBoot enabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002,0003,0005,0001,0004,0006
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9db48a8e-4ca1-4a6d- 
b266-fb916b2b2674,0x800,0x1d1c5000)/File(\EFI
\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive BBS(129,,0x0)

Boot0002* Hard Drive       
BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........O.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. 
.S.S.D. .8.5.0. .E.V.O.   
 .2.5.0.G.B.................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.S.6.R
.X.N.J.0.3.1.6.6.2.6. .B. . . .  
........BO..NO........O.S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. 
.7.5.0. .E.V.O. 
   .2.5.0.G.B.................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.S.S.3 
.B.N.H.0.0.5.1.9.8.5. .R. . . . ........BO

Boot0003* CD/DVD Drive  
BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........O.T.S.S.T.c.o.r.p. 
.C.D.D.V.D.W. 
.S.H.-.2.2.4.D.B.................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9
.R.E.3.8.6.F.D.0.5.3.0.Q.Q. . . . . . ........BO

Boot0004* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0)

Boot0005* UEFI OS   HD(1,GPT,9db48a8e-4ca1-4a6d-
b266-fb916b2b2674,0x800,0x1d1c5000)/File(\EFI
\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)..BO

Boot0006* UEFI:Network Device   BBS(131,,0x0)

78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sdb1/BOOT
/bkpbootx64.efi

78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sdb1/BOOT   
/bootx64.efi

2895d47544fd587b26c7e29be1295c27   sdb1/BOOT
/fbx64.efi

e169c84b62cae5d67d21f3412edf807f   sdb1/BOOT
/grubx64.efi

dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sdb1/BOOT
 /mmx64.efi
e169c84b62cae5d67d21f3412edf807f   sdb1/ubuntu
/grubx64.efi

dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sdb1/ubuntu
/mmx64.efi

78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sdb1/ubuntu
/shimx64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition    
Info =============================

Disks info: 
 
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-
usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 
bytes

sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-
usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3):  

sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-
pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-
ok, update-grub,    farbios

sdb1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, 
nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, 
noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): 

sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  
 no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    
notwinboot

sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  
no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    
notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): 

sda1    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-
without-boot,   not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  
fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

sdb1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-
fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-
fstab,  std-grub.d, sdb

fdisk -l (filtered): 

 Disk sda: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 
488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 775C9C9D-
396F-4B66-9D21-89F3980F2FC1
      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type

sda1   2048 488396799 488394752 232.9G Linux 
filesystem
Disk sdb: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 
488397168 sectors

 Disk identifier: C13CF275-89A7-4C38-
BCE5-2378A910AFB0
      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type

sdb1   2048 488396799 488394752 232.9G EFI System

 parted -lm (filtered): 

sda:250GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 850:;

1:1049kB:250GB:250GB:ext4::;
sdb:250GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 750:;

1:1049kB:250GB:250GB:fat32::boot, esp;

blkid (filtered): 

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 
PARTUUID                             LABEL 
PARTLABEL

sda                                                                                             
└─sda1 ext4     f5046f8e-a21c-44f7-
aa0c-86eb09cf922f ed2bda81-190b-4b82-
b4c7-49243ee64d32       

sdb                                                                                             

└─sdb1 vfat     2F90-9EC4                            
9db48a8e-4ca1-4a6d-b266-fb916b2b2674       

df (filtered): 

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1              179.7G  16% /
sdb1              232.8G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1

Mount options:
sda1              rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

sdb1                 
  rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iochar   
set=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg        
(filtered) ======================


Ubuntu   f5046f8e-a21c-44f7-aa0c-86eb09cf922f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-55-generic   f5046f8e-   
a21c-44f7-aa0c-86eb09cf922f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-53-generic   f5046f8e-  
a21c-44f7-aa0c-86eb09cf922f
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda1/etc/fstab 
(filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       
<dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f5046f8e-a21c-44f7-aa0c-86eb09cf922f /                   
ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation

/swapfile                                 none               
swap    sw              0       0
UUID=2F90-9EC4  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        
0       1

======================= sda1/etc/default/grub    
(filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null 
|| echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda1: Location of files 
loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 
Fragment(s)
  72,135078430 = 77,454450688   boot/grub
/grub.cfg                             1
 103,017910004 = 110,614638592  boot/vmlinuz                                   
1
  76,635093689 = 82,286305280   boot/vmlinuz-
5.8.0-53-generic                  1
 103,017910004 = 110,614638592  boot/vmlinuz-
5.8.0-55-generic                  1
  76,635093689 = 82,286305280   boot/vmlinuz.old                               
1
 107,753547668 = 115,699490816  boot/initrd.img                                
2
  77,960407257 = 83,709349888   boot/initrd.img-
5.8.0-53-generic               2

107,753547668 = 115,699490816  boot/initrd.img-
5.8.0-55-generic               2
  77,960407257 = 83,709349888   
boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/     
(filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17622 gen 13 15:12 
10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 gen 13 15:12    
10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 gen 13 15:12   
20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 gen 13 15:12 30_os-
prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 gen 13 15:12 
30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 gen 13 15:12 
40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 gen 13 15:12 
41_custom

===================== sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg    
(filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid f5046f8e-a21c-44f7-   
aa0c-86eb09cf922f root hd0,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg


Suggested repair: 
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility 
would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of

sda1,
using the following options:           
sdb1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-    
bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-    
    backups  

Final advice in case of suggested repair:

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware 
boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.2 
LTS CurrentSession entry (sdb1/efi
/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the 
final message) file) !

paste.ubuntu.com ko ()
paste.debian.net ko ()
```

What's going on?
How to revert back to the "normal" mode?

Comment: Sounds like it switched to default video. What video card/chip do you have? Did you turn on UEFI Secure boot or have it on before? If you need proprietary driver often easier to have secure boot off to install driver, otherwise you have to manually sign it with mokmanager. If you installed nVidia driver, did you install from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: @oldfred I discovered that the problem, as you rightly pointed out, was the nVidia driver which, I don't know how and why, had problems since yesterday. Through the Ubuntu driver tool I switched to Nouveau driver and the problem disappeared!

Comment: You show UEFI Secure boot on. If you just installed nVidia driver with Secure boot off, it would not be signed and then not used with Secure boot on. You can either sign it or turn off UEFI Secure Boot.

Comment: I'm reading now more about UEFI/SecureBoot because I do not know much about it. Why Nouveau works fine?

Comment: Nouveau is the default & open source, so Ubuntu can sign it. The nVidia driver is a proprietary blob, so Ubuntu cannot sign it. Users are allowed to sign anything if they believe it is secure. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thank you for your kind help and explanation